# After an AJAX call, my JS code doesnt load until I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

So i have a project in Laravel, I have added filters, and it filters the products fine. However, when products are filterd my add to cart buttons become unresponsive. I figured after inspecting the rendered code in the browser that the JS was not loaded. However if i manually refresh the page (or refresh in the code with `location.reload()`) then it works. However I want to avoid manual refresh because then I would lose the colour class added to the button to show that its active filter.

Below is the code for my product file which loads the products in a for loop from the controller:

**products.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">

    <!--Grid row-->
    <div class="row">
    @foreach ($products as $p)
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <form action="{{ route('cart.add', $p->id) }}" data-id="{{ $p->id }}" id="addtocart">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h5>{{ $p -> name }}</h5>
                            <button type="button" id="submit" class="button has-shadow is-danger submit is-small">
                                    Add to Cart
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        {{ $products ->appends($request->query()) -> links() }}
    </div>

</div>
```

**products_show.blade.php** - Where the JS is and where the above file is loaded. The issue occurs after the `$('body').on('click', '.btn-filter'` is called.

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

@section ('content')

    <div class="box text-right">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" name="filter[]" value="Jackets" id="filterJackets" class="button is-info btn-filter">Jackets</button>
            <button type="button" name="filter[]" value="Hoodies" id="filterHoodies" class="button is-info btn-filter">Hoodies</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="products">
        @include('product.products')
    </section>

@endsection


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document)
                .ajaxStart(function () {
                    $("#modal").show();
                })
                .ajaxStop(function () {
                    $("#modal").hide();
                });
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });


            // Pagination
            $('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {

                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                $.ajax({
                    url : url
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $('.products').html(data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Products could not be loaded.');
                });

                window.history.pushState("", "", url);
            });



            // Add to cart
            $(".submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var p_id = $(this).closest("form").data('id');
                var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
                
                var url = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');

                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        product_id:product_id
                    },
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log("added to cart success");
                    },
                });
            });



            $('body').off('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {
                $(this).removeClass("is-success");
            });

            $(".btn-filter").hover(function(){
                $(this).addClass("is-danger");
            }, function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("is-danger");
            });



            var filters = [];

            $('body').on('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass('is-success');

                filters = []; // reset
                
                $('button[name="filter[]"]').each(function()
                {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("is-success")) {
                        filters.push($(this).val());
                    }
                });

                var url = '{{ route('products.type') }}'+'?filter[storage]='+filters

                $.ajax({
                    url : url
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $('.products').html(data);
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Products could not be loaded.');
                });

                window.history.pushState("", "", url);

            });

        });
    </script>
```

I am not sure if the php code matters because the problem here is the add to cart button JS is not being called, but here it is anyways:

```
public function filterByType(Request $request){
        $products = QueryBuilder::for(Auth::user()->products())
            ->allowedFilters(['type'])->paginate()
            ->appends(request()->query());

        // Check if request is from ajax
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return view('product.products', ['products' => $products])->render();
        }

        return view('product.products_show', compact('products'));

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: where you put your script ? i think you need to `push` your js into `layouts.app` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a hackway to do this, However is there a better solution or a way to fix my issue? And is what i did here bad?:

I added `location.reload()` to the end of the `btn-filter` on click which will reload the page since reloading the page fixes the issue for me.

I then added the code below to the top of the script:

```
var window_url = window.location.href;
var url_filter_params = window_url.substr(window_url.indexOf("=") + 1)
var filter_params_array = url_filter_params.split(',');

$('button[name="filter[]"]').each(function()
{
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), filter_params_array) >= 0){
        $(this).addClass('is-success');
    }
});
```

This basically gets the URL parses it to get the params, and then shows adds the is-warning class back to the button to make it appear as selected. The filters also work.